# Relation implementation (Parent and children)

Tags: podio

In the context where we have `Projects` that contain `Tasks` (two Apps), which one is better and why?

1. In the `Projects` App, add a relation field to its children `Tasks`.
2. In the `Tasks` App, add a relation field to its parent `Projet`.

On the Podio API POV, you would get the field values (1) or the referenced items (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the relation field to Tasks for the simple reason that you can then create the relation when you create each task. Otherwise you have to go back and edit the project every time you want to create a new task.